# React-datepicker is opening with delay onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, delay, react-datepicker

i'm facing a strange issue with react-datepicker. I've made my datepicker compatible with redux form and the code is here:

```
<DatePicker
  customInput={<CustomDateInputNew {...props} />}
  onChange={date => {
    props.input.onChange(date ? formatValueToState(date) : "");
    if (props.onSelect) {
      props.onSelect(date);
    }
  }}
  dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
  openToDate={props.openToDate}
  selected={
    props.input.value ? parseStateToValue(props.input.value) : undefined
  }
  filterDate={day => isDateUnavailable(day, props.availability)}
  locale={moment.locale("en-gb")} //sets monday first day of week
/>
```

The filterDate function show as enable the dates that are contained inside an array and her implemantation is this:

```
export const isDateUnavailable = (day, daysArray) => {
  if (!days) {
    return true;
  }
  return days.filter(item => moment(item).isSame(day)).length > 0;
};
```

where days is an array with the format ['2018-09-09']. This datepicker will show the dates that contained inside this array. I'm facing and issue with the datepicker appearing after tw0 or three seconds after clicking. Why is this happening? Does any other face the same or a relative issue? Is it something with the filterDates?? Thanks!

Comment: Your `isDateUnavailable` is pretty heavy, so I can image it taking 2-3 seconds for the date picker to initialize when running that on all potential dates. I think it would be better to give the date picker an array of dates you would like instead, with the `includeDates` prop.

Comment: To determine if the `isDateUnavailable` is the problem, like  @Tholle said, try a simple return in `isDateUnavailable` and see if the delays persist or improves.

Comment: Also using the exact format to parse the date string could make things faster: `moment(item, 'YYYY-MM-DD');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `isDateUnavailable` function is pretty heavy, so I can image it taking 2-3 seconds for the date picker to initialize when running that on all potential dates.

I think it would be better to give the date picker your `props.availability` array as dates you would like to be able to select instead, with the `includeDates` prop.

**Example**

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DatePicker
        includeDates={[
          moment("2018-09-09"),
          moment("2018-09-09").subtract(1, "days")
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My array could be of great size. It can have many elements. How to do this with many elements?

Comment: @user7334203 Try `includeDates={props.availability.map(d => moment(d)}` and see if it goes any faster than what you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

I agree about `isDateUnavailable` heaviness.

You could just make it lighter and see what happens.

```
export const checkAvailability = (availableDays) => 
  (!availableDays) 
  ? () => true // If the array is empty, just create a function which returns always true!
  : (currentDay) => 
    availableDays.filter(
      dayString => dayString === currentDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    ).lenght > 0;
```

and use it like this

```
filterDate={checkAvailability(props.availability)}
```

Basically, instead of creating a moment object from every single item in the days array, it just formats the day (from the datepicker) in your format. Then it compares strings (which should be faster!).